# How can I save read dataframes as list in R?

Tags: r

I have say about 10 `.txt` files in my directory that I read like this:

```
sampleFiles <- list.files(directory)
for (i in 1:length(sampleFiles)) {
 table <- read.table( sampleFiles[i], header = TRUE)
}
```

I want to store the read file such that I can access them as `table1` for `i=1`, `table2` for `i=2` and `tablen` for `i=n`. How can I read all these files and save as dataframe base names `table`?

Comment: To save them as a list use `table <- lapply(sampleFiles,read.table,header=TRUE)` instead of a for loop.  You can then access them as `table[[1]]` etc

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply`

```
Data <- lapply( list.files(directory), read.table, header=TRUE)
```

In order to access each data.frame you can use `[[` as in `Data[[1]]`, `Data[[2]]`,...,`Data[[n]]`

Read about how to [Extract or Replace Parts of an Object](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) using `[[`

Answer (score 0):

To name them as you describe, replace the `table <-` assignment in your loop with

```
assign(paste0("table", j), read.table(sampleFiles[j], header = TRUE))
```

Your question title is slightly misleading, as this is not saving the tables as a list in the formal R sense of a list (for which, see the other answer).